# Why does array append does not work + Postgres

Tags: arrays, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

Trying to append an array to an array does not seem to work.

```
DO
$do$
DECLARE
  COUNTER INTEGER = 0;
  CRNS bigint [];
  TMPS bigint [];
BEGIN
  WHILE COUNTER < 2 LOOP
    TMPS := ARRAY(select plain_crn from call_records where timestamp=1467981702966);
    array_append(CRNS,TMPS);
    RAISE NOTICE '%',CRNS;
    COUNTER := COUNTER + 1;
  END LOOP;  
END
$do$;
```

Seem to get the following error

```
ERROR:  function array_append(bigint[], bigint[]) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT array_append(CRNS,TMPS)
           ^
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `array_append()` appends an element to an array. You should concatanate two arrays with the operator `||`.

```
DO
$do$
DECLARE
  COUNTER INTEGER = 0;
  CRNS bigint [];
BEGIN
  WHILE COUNTER < 2 LOOP
    CRNS := CRNS || ARRAY(select plain_crn from call_records where timestamp=1467981702966);
    RAISE NOTICE '%',CRNS;
    COUNTER := COUNTER + 1;
  END LOOP;  
END
$do$;
```